# How to activate a lever with another lever?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to build a Wimpy in minecraft, and it uses a rail system to deliver food. I have two sides of the restaurant, but one rail switching between the two sides. A redstone torch doesnt work, so I need to activate the lever with another lever from the kitchen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using an inverter?  Levers are emitters, not receivers.  An inverter will work both as an emitter and receiver

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Levers can not interact with other levers. To get a similar effect you could use memory cells and buttons. [Wiki entry on logic gates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Basic_Logic_Gates).

Components that would be of interest:

- XOR (Only returns true if one input is true but not both)
- Memory Cells (Allows the system to remember button presses)
- Monostable circuit (Allows altering of redstone signal duration)

To get the track to switch try powering the block below the intersection with a torch or repeater.